# docker compose entrypoint cp using wildcard: cp: cannot stat /foo/*.txt

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In a docker-compose.yml file, I have an entrypoint which should copy files to a bind mount so that I can retrieve them from the host:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  my-service:
  ....
  entrypoint: cp /foo/*.txt /data
  volumes:
    - ./data:/data
```

But each time I run this container, the log says: `cp: cannot stat '/foo/*.txt': No such file or directory`. On the other hand, if I enter a full file name, it works very well.

I also tried: `entrypoint: ['cp', '/foo/*.txt', '/data']` but the same error occurs.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact

How could I use a wildcard for copying files in my compose service?

Info:

```
docker --version
Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f

cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DESCRIPTION
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works (and I cannot test it now): `entrypoint: sh -c 'cp /foo/*.txt /data'`

Comment: It seems to work, but what I don't really understand is that running `entrypoint: cp /foo/*.txt /data` should already be called with `/bin/sh -c` in front in such so-called "shell form" according to: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact

Comment: I'm thinking that docker-compose is parsing the `cp /foo/*.txt /data` as `cp /foo/\*.txt /data`. And therefore the `*` is taken as character and not as wildcard.

Comment: How do you run the container? Are you using `docker run`? If so, try *debugging* with `strace docker run`, maybe you could see the reason why the container is failing. (the wildcard is taken as character perhaps)

Answer (score 2):

Characters like `*` are interpreted by the shell, so you need to invoke a shell to handle it (e.g., `sh -c 'cp /foo/*.txt /data'`). Otherwise, those parameters are being passed to `exec`, which does not know how to handle `*`, and the error you've described happens.